# Create a new dataframe according to the contrast between two similar df

Tags: r, dataframe, compare-contrast

I have a dataframe made like this:

```
  X Y  Z T
  1 2  4 2
  3 2  1 4
  7 5 NA 3
```

After several steps (not important which one) i obtained this df:

```
  X Y Z T
  1 2 4 2
  3 2 NA 4
  7 5 NA 3
```

i want to obtain a new dataframe made by only the rows **which didn't change during the steps**; the result would be this one:

```
 X  Y  Z  T
 1  2  4  2
 7  5  NA 3
```

How could I do?

Comment: Just a `merge` isn't it - `merge(dt1,dt2)` ?

Comment: @zx8754 this might not be a duplicate as the join might not be a correct answer, depending on the structure of the data.

Comment: @ira based on example data provided, and expected output, it is a simple `merge` by all columns, pointed out above by thelatemail.

Comment: @zx8754 the example might be simplified. This line `i want to obtain a new dataframe made by only the rows which didn't change during the steps; ` does not appear to request a result of a join.

Comment: @zx8754 no, merge doesn't give me the result that I expect. Akrun gave me the solution

Comment: I think it could not be classified as a duplicate of a "merge" question. This is only my humble vision :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option with `base R` would be to `paste` the rows of each dataset together and compare (`==`) to create a logical vector which we use for subsetting the new dataset

```
dfO[do.call(paste, dfO) == do.call(paste, df),]
#   X Y  Z T
#1 1 2  4 2
#3 7 5 NA 3
```

where 'dfO' is the old dataset and 'df' is the new

Answer (score 4):

You can use dplyr's `intersect` function:

```
library(dplyr)
intersect(d1, d2)
#  X Y  Z T
#1 1 2  4 2
#2 7 5 NA 3
```

This is a data.frame-equivalent of base R's `intersect` function.

In case you're working with `data.table`s, that package also provides such a function:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d1)
setDT(d2)
fintersect(d1, d2)
#   X Y  Z T
#1: 1 2  4 2
#2: 7 5 NA 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Another `dplyr` solution: `semi_join`.

```
dt1 %>% semi_join(dt2, by = colnames(.))
  X Y  Z T
1 1 2  4 2
2 7 5 NA 3
```

**Data**

```
dt1 <- read.table(text = "X Y  Z T
  1 2  4 2
  3 2  1 4
  7 5 NA 3",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dt2 <- read.table(text = "  X Y Z T
  1 2 4 2
                  3 2 NA 4
                  7 5 NA 3",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid that neither `semi join`, nor `intersect` or `merge` are the correct answers. `merge` and `intersect` will not handle duplicate rows properly. semi join will change order of the rows.

From this perspective, I think the only correct one so far is akrun's.

You could also do something like:

```
df1[rowSums(((df1 == df2) | (is.na(df1) & is.na(df2))), na.rm = T) == ncol(df1),]
```

But I think akrun's way is more elegant and likely to perform better in terms of speed.

Comment: That being said, all of the answers might be ok if you don't have duplicate rows or if you do not care about order of the rows...